# PHP mysql_close() and mysql_free_result() - at what point should I be using them?

Tags: php, mysql

I've been using Dreamweaver to develop PHP and MySQL based websites, but as it tends to overdo simple things I normally write my own queries and PHP to handle the results.

After doing a more complex page, I can have up to 5 `SELECTs` and as many `UPDATEs`, maybe more in loops etc.

Persistent connections are *not* being used, and I only connect to the database once per script.

What I want to know is, given that I only connect to MySQL once, does the amount / complexity of queries have much impact with regards to MySQL connections, and do I *ever* need to explictly call `mysql_close()` in my scripts?

Also at what point should I start using `mysql_free_result()` (or should I be using it anyway?)

A psuedo-example of the type of thing I'm concerned about:

```
connect to database;

aSelect;

do {
    anUpdate;
} while(select has rows);

anotherSelect;

anotherSelect;

anUpdate;

do {
    aSelect;
    anUpdate;
} while (anotherSelect has rows);

anotherUpdate;

aVeryBigSelect;

//end of file
//no mysql_free_result() or mysql_close() calls, should there be?
```

Comment: About the only time you'd need to mysql_close() is if you're using a long-running script and the database is not needing during the main long-term loop. Otherwise PHP will clean up for you when the script exits and close the connection for you.

Comment: this seems to be the case - thanks. I'm still getting used to PHP, coming off of Java development I'm consistently surprised and / or suspicious when things like this crop up - Java doesn't clean stuff up for you, generally speaking :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the scripts are running for a very short time, like to deliver a web page, it's alright not to call `mysql_close` and `mysql_free_result`, since PHP will close the connection and free the memory automatically at the end of your web page execution.

On the other hand, if you'll write a long running batch script, doing thousands of query, it may be a good idea to call `mysql_free_result`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to call mysql_close() yourself, the connection is closed when the script finishes.

You can call mysql_free_result() if your query returned a large result set and this causes you to run out of memory. But as a rule of thumb, only to this if you actually run into problems.

Comment: _only to this if you actually run into problems_ Whose rule is that?

Comment: is there any overhead to calling it - i.e if you call mysql_close() at the end of all your scripts as a rule of thumb, does this do any harm?

Comment: Haha all this commotion about my "rule of thumb" expression. My point is, why add all these function calls if they are not needed. It does not harm if you call them, but they are not necessary in most cases, and the question was if he needs to call these functions.

Answer (score -1):

It is important to close the database connection when you don't need it anymore. (security)

Once you don't need the result of a query anymore and you're low on memory, you should call `mysql_free_result();`
This could, for example, be done after looping through the results of a query.

Comment: agree with the Colonel, are there security implications with leaving a DB connection open during the execution of a script?

Comment: I once read that the database connection is not closed immediately after script execution. (via timeout) - so a hacker might get access to the database. Not sure about that though.

Comment: i can see how that *may* be vulnerable to a man in the middle style attack, but if it was, then it would be vulnerable as soon as the connection was made - although I'm not claiming to know much of security ofcourse

Comment: The longer you have an open connection, the easier it is for someone to hack you.